# Trying to pivot multiple columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query which dynamically generates different number of rows, with varying ID column values. I need to be able to PIVOT this into a columnar result. My current data result is below.

```
ID    Caption    FieldName     FieldType
---   ---------  ------------  ------------ 
10    Caption 1  Field Name 1  Field Type 1 
11    Caption 2  Field Name 2  Field Type 2 
12    Caption 3  Field Name 3  Field Type 3 
20    Caption 4  Field Name 4  Field Type 4 
30    Caption 5  Field Name 5  Field Type 5
```

My desired result is

```
10            11            12            20            30
--------      ----------    ---------     ---------     --------- 
Caption 1     Caption 2     Caption 3     Caption 4     Caption 5
Field Name 1  Field Name 2  Field Name 3  Field Name 4  Field Name 5
Field Type 1  Field Type 2  Field Type 3  Field Type 4  Field Type 5
```

Please note that the values 10, 11, 12, 20 and 30 can change to be something else, so I understand that I need to do some dynamic sql. I want to avoid using CURSORS if possible.

Any suggestions are welcome. Please excuse the formatting

Comment: If you understand you need to do some dynamic sql, why don't you include the code you have already tried in the post?

Comment: I only looked at another post to understand I have to do, but am unsure of how to paste my code here. The @ gives me some error when tryign to paste code..

Comment: I'm not even sure if this one can be called PIVOT. It looks like you are trying to transpose the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **2005 Version**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(ID)+'=max(case when Item='+cast(ID as varchar(25))+' then Value else null end)' From  YourTable Order By 1 For XML Path('') ),1,1,'')
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Seq],'+@SQL +'
 From   (
         Select Item=A.ID,B.* 
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply ( 
                       Select Seq=1,Value=cast(A.Caption   as varchar(max))  Union All
                       Select Seq=2,Value=cast(A.FieldName as varchar(max))  Union All
                       Select Seq=3,Value=cast(A.FieldType as varchar(max))
                      ) B
        ) A
Group By Seq
Order By Seq
'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind going dynamic

I'm hesitant to remove SEQ (the first column of the results).  You can remove `[SEQ],` from the final query, but I am not sure it would maintain the proper sequence on a larger data set.

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(ID) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Seq],' + @SQL + '
  From (
        Select Item=A.ID,B.* 
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                       Select Seq=1,Value=cast(A.Caption   as varchar(max)) Union All
                       Select Seq=2,Value=cast(A.FieldName as varchar(max)) Union All
                       Select Seq=3,Value=cast(A.FieldType as varchar(max))
                     ) B
       ) A
 Pivot (max(value) For Item in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

[image]

> **EDIT - With SEQ Removed from the final Select**

[image]

Comment: The results are what I want, but I get a syntax error while using the code above. It gives me a syntax error new Values

Comment: It depends. I am getting a list of fields being displayed on a page. I am trying to create a generic script, so that this outputs these into a format that can be exported to excel. These excel sheet can then by filled with data for testing automation. The number of these fields could vary from 10-60

Comment: Prior to generation of the output that I listed above for pivoting, I do a lot of manipulation by adding or removing some fields based on certain condition. So, the ID column may not consistently so the same values from page to page

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Values'.

Just to confirm. This is T-SQL right?

Comment: @gsva Yup SQL Sever.  Just curious what version are you on?

Comment: Cannot use a UDF. It is SQL Server 2005. I looked up values and it appears to be something new in 2008

Comment: @gsva Wish you mentioned 2005.  FYI. in SO, when you tag SQL Server, it is assumed currently supported versions 2012+.  Pivot and Cross Apply are not supported in 2005

Comment: @gsva Added a 2005 version.  I was wrong Cross Apply is supported in 2005